# Make SDL_AudioCallback seamless (ie. no hiccup)?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am writing a simple program to play a sound via SDL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>


float sine_freq = 200.0f;
float audio_volume = 1.0f;
float audio_frequency;

void SineAudioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len) {
    float* buf = (float*)stream;
    for (int i = 0; i < len / 4; ++i) {
        buf[i] = (float)(audio_volume * sin(2 * M_PI * i * audio_frequency));
    }
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO)) {
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "[SDL] Audio driver: " << SDL_GetCurrentAudioDriver() << std::endl;

    SDL_AudioSpec want, have;
    SDL_zero(want);

    want.freq = 5000;
    want.format = AUDIO_F32;
    want.channels = 2;
    want.samples = 4096;
    want.callback = SineAudioCallback;

    std::cout <<"[SDL] Desired - frequency: " << want.freq
        << ", format: f " << SDL_AUDIO_ISFLOAT(want.format)  << " s " << SDL_AUDIO_ISSIGNED(want.format) << " be " << SDL_AUDIO_ISBIGENDIAN(want.format) << " sz " << SDL_AUDIO_BITSIZE(want.format)
        << ", channels: " << (int)want.channels << ", samples: " << want.samples << std::endl;


    SDL_AudioDeviceID dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &want, &have, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);

    if (!dev) {
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }


    std::cout << "[SDL] Desired - frequency: " << have.freq
        << ", format: f " << SDL_AUDIO_ISFLOAT(have.format) << " s " << SDL_AUDIO_ISSIGNED(have.format) << " be " << SDL_AUDIO_ISBIGENDIAN(have.format) << " sz " << SDL_AUDIO_BITSIZE(have.format)
        << ", channels: " << (int)have.channels << ", samples: " << have.samples << std::endl;

    audio_frequency = sine_freq / have.freq;

    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
    SDL_Delay(10000);

    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(dev);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine; however, when I run this program, I notice a very slight but perceptible "silent hiccup" when the callback is called. I'm guessing that since the callback is only called once the buffer itself has run out of data, the silence is the slight delay it takes to re-fill the buffer.

I want to get rid of this "silent hiccup". My use case is such that I receive a stream of audio data (from elsewhere); I want to simultaneously fill this SDL audio buffer with this data while allowing the SDL to consume the buffer. However, it doesn't seem like I can access the actual stream/buffer unless it's in the callback, but by then, the buffer has run out of data already.

Is there a more elegant solution to this? I prefer not using SDL_mixer if possible.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to call `std::cout << "here" << std::endl;` from within your audio callback (or indeed to perform any kind of I/O there) since that can cause the callback to take longer than expected to return, resulting in buffer underruns.

Comment: Why all those C-style casts?

Answer (score 0):

> However, it doesn't seem like I can access the actual stream/buffer unless it's in the callback

That's what the [`SDL_QueueAudio`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_QueueAudio) function is for, you can take over the buffer upload timing.